# Is there a jquery video player that handle mp4 video files?

Tags: jquery

I need to find a jquery video player that can play mp4 files.

please help me

Thanks.

Comment: You just need a JS video player that handles MP4, not a jQuery-specific video player... (At least, in my opinion.)

Comment: searching "jquery video player +mp4" in google gave me http://jquery.malsup.com/media/

Answer (score 0):

I've come across a couple of free jQuery based video player scripts:

http://flarevideo.com/

http://videojs.com/jquery/

Both of those first try a HTML5 video tag then fallback to Flash.